# Creating a function that reads a text file from a data-feed and turning it into an object file for php

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, text-parsing, datafeed

I am creating a store website, but the datafeed I receive is a format separated by bars instead of commas. I want to be able to read from the text file to display the content into a web page and allow the client to search through the merchandise.

Example row:

```
710734240|8mm - Men's Freemason Ring / Masonic Ring - Gold and Black Inlay Tungsten Ring Comfort Fit|73628|
```

I tried the looping over the separated items and putting each of them into their own array.

```
        const my_data = 'test_data.txt';

        async function getData() {

            const response = await fetch(my_data);
            const data = await response.text();
            //console.log(data);

            const rows = data.split('\n').splice(1);
            rows.forEach(elt => {
                const row = elt.split('|');

                row.forEach(item => {
                    const items = item.split(',');
                    //    const filtered = items.filter(function (el){
                    //    return el != ""; 
                    const lens = items.length;
                    //document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = rows + "<br>";

                    var goods = {
                        ProductId: row[0],
                        Name: row[1],
                        MechantId: row[2],
                        Mechant: row[3],
                        link: row[4],
                        thumbnail: row[5],
                        bigImage: row[6],
                        Price: row[7],
                        RetailPrice: row[8],
                        mainCat: row[9],
                        subCat: row[10],
                        Description: row[11],

                    };
                    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = goods.Description + "<br>";
                });


                console.log(row);
                //console.log(lens);



            });
        }
        getData();
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: How to turn a datafeed into json data to use on a web page.

Comment: can you share an example about the text file?

Comment: here is an example of the text and this is only one line.

Comment: 710734240|8mm - Men's Freemason Ring / Masonic Ring - Gold and Black Inlay Tungsten Ring Comfort Fit|73628|

Comment: Update your question, please do not post unformattable comments

Comment: So split `const items = item.split('|');`

Comment: What is PHP's "_object file_", and how is the title even related to the question, where you say you want to convert a pipe-separated list to a JS array ..?

Comment: listen every one I apologize about the way I am describing my problem but it is hard to explain without being able to show you my dilenma.

Comment: I already was ab to split the text files now I have each item in its own array. Now I need to be able to access each item individually as and object in JSON format as shown in my code.

Comment: This crashes to "JSON", there's no JSON in your code ... If you mean the JS object you've constructed, that seems to be OK. What is the issue here? You can't access an object property, like `goods.ProductId`, or you want to iterate through the object?

Comment: I want to be able to iterate through them all the sample is just a fraction there is at least 12 object out of an array of 51 from each array and hundreds of items.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to start with this:

```js
let list = {};

const rows = `710734240|8mm - Men's Freemason Ring / Masonic Ring - Gold and Black Inlay Tungsten Ring Comfort Fit|73628|
710734241|9mm - Men's Freemason Ring / Masonic Ring - Gold and Black Inlay Tungsten Ring Comfort Fit|73628|
710734242|10mm - Men's Freemason Ring / Masonic Ring - Gold and Black Inlay Tungsten Ring Comfort Fit|73628|`
  .split("\n")
  .forEach(row => { // destructing the rows curtesy of Code Maniac
    ( 
      ([ProductId, Description, subCat]) => list[ProductId] = { Description, subCat }  
    )( row.split("|") )
  })


// displaying example

let dl = document.createElement("dl");
let content = []
Object.keys(list).forEach(
  k => content.push(`<dt>${k}</dt><dd>${list[k].Description}</dd>`)
)
dl.innerHTML = content.join("");
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(dl)
```

```css
dl {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: solid #333;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
}

dt {
  flex-basis: 10%;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background: #333;
  text-align: right;
  color: #fff;
}

dd {
  flex-basis: 80%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: This looks promising I wish there was a way to send you the file and you can see fro yourself but this is in the ball park.